# LLVM scc_iterator crashes when I use scc_begin on CallGraph

Tags: llvm

I'm using the scc_iterator on an LLVM CallGraph.

Here's how I get it the CallGraph:

```
CallGraph &CG = getAnalysis<CallGraphWrapperPass>().getCallGraph();
CG.dump();
```

This causes the segfault:

```
scc_iterator<CallGraph*> SCCI = scc_begin(&CG)
```

These are the the passes I've registered:

```
legacy::PassManager passManager;
passManager.add(new llvm::CallGraphWrapperPass);
passManager.add(new me::myPass);
```

Additional Notes:
When I dump the callGraph I get this:

```
Call graph node <<null function>><<0x21d2910>>  #uses=0
CS<0x0> calls function 'qux'
CS<0x0> calls function 'syscall'
CS<0x0> calls function 'id'
CS<0x0> calls function 'llvm.dbg.declare'
CS<0x0> calls function 'foo'
CS<0x0> calls function 'bar'
CS<0x0> calls function 'main'
CS<0x0> calls function 'llvm.dbg.value'
Call graph node for function: 'bar'<<0x21ceb10>>  #uses=2
CS<0x21cf9c0> calls function 'syscall'

Call graph node for function: 'foo'<<0x21ceba0>>  #uses=2
CS<0x21cf168> calls function 'qux'
CS<0x21cf380> calls function 'id'

Call graph node for function: 'id'<<0x21d2640>>  #uses=2

Call graph node for function: 'llvm.dbg.declare'<<0x21d01b0>>  #uses=1

Call graph node for function: 'llvm.dbg.value'<<0x21d0a10>>  #uses=1

Call graph node for function: 'main'<<0x21ceb70>>  #uses=1
CS<0x21d08e8> calls function 'foo'
CS<0x21d0aa8> calls function 'bar'

Call graph node for function: 'qux'<<0x21ce8e0>>  #uses=2
CS<0x21cd3b0> calls function 'syscall'

Call graph node for function: 'syscall'<<0x21ce940>>  #uses=3
CS<0x0> calls external node
```

Backtrace:
https://pastebin.com/46e5sr5p

Comment: What's the crash message? Is it assert failing or what?

Comment: I've added the BackTrace through pastebin

Comment: Probably one of the nodes is null. You need to check something like `if(node)`, before proceeding with your analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using llvm 4.0. Upgrading to llvm 5.0 seems to be working.